# Secure streaming audio/video in JAVA

Tags: java, opencv, video-streaming, webcam, rtp

I'm doing project for my university and I'm stuck with several problems. It's a team project, so we designed an app which core functionality would be secure streaming AV from few cameras (our destination target are IP cameras). We assumed that JMF is not enough for us, so we have found OpenCV library which has JAVA API what is ideal for us since JAVA is our language of choice but I am aware that languages such as C++ would done better for this kind of work, but we haven't sufficient experience and a little time remaining.

What we have accomplished for now:

- We have found and tested ZRTP protocol implementation ZRTP4J and we want to used it for secure transmission (no one should be able to overhear a conversation and now we are also thinking about certification so we would authorize the caller)
- We can capture frames from the webcam using OpenCV but we have problems with transmitting it via RTP using JMF implementation of this protocol
- We can encode captured sequence of frames to specific format using Xuggler library and pack it to media container

In other words we have frames captured by OpenCV, we want to mux captured frames with captured audio from a microphone and send it over RTP protocol which uses UDP in transport layer. The question is how to do this properly? Should we use some muxer before streaming and demuxer on the output? Or maybe we should have 2 different streams, first for the video and latter for audio?

The JMF itself is other problem. We have to care about its AV formats applicable for RTP transmition and its API is rough and mastering it takes much time for us and the fact that this library is old and not developed anymore doesn't motivate us at all. Could someone of you point some tested, verified RTP implementation for JAVA? We are also open for other propositions, maybe we are mistaken at more points in our design.

Thank you in advance!
Hubert

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use muxer and demuxer in streaming video and audio frames. You should use 2 streams, one for video and the other for audio. I recommend you read RFC3550.

Maybe you could try this Java RTP library [jlibrtp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jlibrtp/?source=typ_redirect)

ZRTP4J is a library for key negotiation. you still need a SRTP library to encrypt and decrypt packets. The SRTP library may use the key obtained from ZRTP. I've found a open source project [jitsi-jingle](https://code.google.com/p/jitsi-jingle/source/browse/trunk/jitsi-jingle-lib/src/com/phono/srtplight/?r=9) using SRTP.